# Regularity of maximum function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Given a smooth function $f=f(x,y)$, $(x,y)\in \Omega_1\times\Omega_2$ ($\Omega_i\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ are bounded, smooth, and every other nice property you need), what is the most that can be said about the regularity of the function  $Mf(x)=\max_{y\in\Omega_2}f(x,y)$? I think it's pretty clear that $Mf$ should be continuous in $x$. Can it be more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall properties of the composition $M \circ f$ are limited by the regularity of $M$. In particular, if $f$ and $\Omega \, \dot= \, \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ are regular, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\Omega$. From this it easily follows that $M \circ f$ is Lipschitz continuous as well.

The following example also proves that this is the maximum regularity that can in general be expected. Consider $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $\Omega = [-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ and $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as follows
$$
f(x,y) = xy
$$
Then one has $Mf(x) = |x|$ which is just Lipschitz continuous as claimed.